# Play embedded f4v file in flash?

Tags: flash, movie

Hi is it possible to play an embedded f4v file in flash?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a wizard for adding a video to a swf you find it under **File|Import|Import Video...**. But it's not really recomendable. You often get out of sync video/audio. Plus the swf file will be huge.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the file with swfObject's parameter.  It also depends on what type of player you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the answer is a big fat **no**. I know, I know – it's awful.

You cannot feed embedded movie or aac data into the Flash Player's "native" media player. It can only play these files from a NetStream. You *can* play embeeded *mp3s* (and some other lossless formats) but you want video, I see.

I'ma see if I can do some hijacking and let you know if I succeed, but I'm not hopeful.

From this article about [this stunningly bizzare oversight](http://kaioa.com/node/81)...

> flash.media.Video requires a flash.net.NetStream. This means you cannot load embedded videos..."